# The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian InRelease' is not signed in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I `git push` to a branch in codecommit and I started receiving this messages. Until yesterday everything was fine and I don't have access to any type of configuration in aws.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using anything from sbt repo, you can remove it from sources before running apt update

```
rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
```